# CSS - Default style flashes rather than my custom style

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I have the following button - using the foundation framework.

The problem I'm facing is for a brief second when my page loads the buttons default background colour is shown before using the background-colour I'm setting. `optionColorsForButtons` is an array.

```
<button style="background-color:{{optionColorsForButtons[$index]}}"
                 type="button" class="small button">
</button>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get around this?

The only solution I can think of is I duplicate Foundation's button class and set the background colour there (so that it doesnt effect other buttons). However I dont really like the idea of duplicate code in that way.

Any ideas appreciated.

p.s. I'm using SASS.

Thanks.

Comment: The `style` attribute will not be compiled by SASS. So this problem means that you don't use SASS in that button, you are using SASS in the scss files. Instead, create a class named `.other-background` or what you want, that have the `background-color` property  in scss files, and then add the class to the element `<button class="other-background">`

Comment: Ok - so that would be in the foundation scss file?

Comment: Yeah, all CSS written outside the SCSS file will not be compiled, so you can't use variables, mixins, etc. It's really obvious since you need to compile SCSS files to transform to normal pure CSS files. I don't know why you attempt to use a variable in a HTML file (impossible, no way). Other thing: you said `I dont really like the idea of duplicate code in that way`, but I preffer duplicate a class and not write inline styles, due specificity and cleaner code.

Comment: If i say have my style in the class `detail1Colour` - and have the following HTML, can I ensure that the class `detail1Colour` is applied before the class `button`?  `class="detail1Colour small button"`

Comment: if you are adding your custom CSS, after the foundation default CSS, it will work.